# Kusto - All data per id for max date

Tags: kql, azure-log-analytics-workspace

Kusto - All data per id for max date

Hi,
I am struggeling with a query and hope someone can help me with this topic. :)
I want to get all data per ID related to the latest timestamp.
My source looks something like this:

| Timestamp | ID | Other columns |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Date A | ID A | other data 1 |
| Date A | ID A | other data 2 |
| Date B | ID B | other data 1 |
| Date B | ID B | other data 2 |
| Date C | ID A | other data 1 |
| Date C | ID A | other data 2 |
| Date D | ID B | other data 1 |
| Date D | ID B | other data 2 |

As result i want:

| Timestamp | ID | Other columns |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Date A | ID A | other data 1 |
| Date A | ID A | other data 2 |
| Date B | ID B | other data 1 |
| Date B | ID B | other data 2 |

So for the ID A and B (and so on) all rows with the same (max)timestamp related to the ID.

I tried --> source | summarize arg_max(timestamp) by ID

That results in only in:

| Timestamp | ID | Other columns |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Date A | ID A | other data 1 |
| Date B | ID B | other data 1 |

If I add further columns to the summarize i got a amount of rows depending of the different entries in the other column, but also with timestamps that are not the latest.
query:
source | summarize arg_max(timestamp) by ID, other column

result:

| Timestamp | ID | Other columns |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Date A | ID A | other data 1 |
| Date A | ID A | other data 2 |
| Date B | ID B | other data 1 |
| Date B | ID B | other data 2 |
| Date C | ID A | other data 1 |
| Date C | ID A | other data 2 |
| Date D | ID B | other data 1 |
| Date D | ID B | other data 2 |

Hopes that is understandle. I am grateful for any input

Thanks in advance

Marcus

Comment: "Data X" as a timestamp? Why is "Date A" bigger than "Date C"? if you are not using real timestamps, at least use integers

Comment: Timestamp is a datetime, so  "sort","max", "min" etc. is useable

Comment: Your intention is clear, but your data sample is not usable.

Answer (score 0):

###### Option 1.

```
datatable(Timestamp:int, ID:string, OtherColumns:string)
[
    4 ,"A" ,"other data 1"
   ,4 ,"A" ,"other data 2"
   ,3 ,"B" ,"other data 1"
   ,3 ,"B" ,"other data 2"
   ,2 ,"A" ,"other data 1"
   ,2 ,"A" ,"other data 2"
   ,1 ,"B" ,"other data 1"
   ,1 ,"B" ,"other data 2"
]
|   partition hint.strategy=native by ID
    (
            order by Timestamp desc
        |   extend  rr = row_rank(Timestamp)
        |   where rr == 1
        |   project-away rr
    )
```

| Timestamp | ID | OtherColumns |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | A | other data 1 |
| 4 | A | other data 2 |
| 3 | B | other data 1 |
| 3 | B | other data 2 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA32RTwvCMAzF74N9h7CTgylMPQk7%20OfiyYs3Eak2aNW1I4vOgR/ezDlFmLbQQn7vJeVVK5a9PWNnaVLMWaXZyFiOYD4b5UzG7iNY8AFp6s6X1OavYuh7K98DWUOIgnEgh6tUoKUbxMGTRW2s/2IDKU9%20%20NpY4%20v/mdfGGl/8Z14bq3xr37sLzxSxYeMsHCSaniSgGPdlYhWbK8K2lLDqMDr11SxHWtoJf2cLGvPdR1R1xxuj1QBEkAC5YkPKnj6/EX6rC3kgPrUJxN8oI3fEHXdVoUpR1DB8AJaP6gDhAQAA)

###### Option 2.

```
let t = datatable(Timestamp:int, ID:string, OtherColumns:string)
[
    4 ,"A" ,"other data 1"
   ,4 ,"A" ,"other data 2"
   ,3 ,"B" ,"other data 1"
   ,3 ,"B" ,"other data 2"
   ,2 ,"A" ,"other data 1"
   ,2 ,"A" ,"other data 2"
   ,1 ,"B" ,"other data 1"
   ,1 ,"B" ,"other data 2"
];
t
|   summarize Timestamp = max(Timestamp) by ID
|   join kind=inner t on ID, Timestamp
|   project-away *1
```

| ID | Timestamp | OtherColumns |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 4 | other data 1 |
| A | 4 | other data 2 |
| B | 3 | other data 1 |
| B | 3 | other data 2 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA32QPQ%20CQAyGdxL%20Q8Mk5hxAJwyDH4uTi5txOOSih9wdgRLF%20OMtX7IgbdKhz/u2yZsKBIQQYo7UUSpmJ6lEgVxlgdTI4LAPCsylvjE44l3kO5OWShfd0rWts20B1QqYs3FomFrV3APPaRgbY37HlrTe/vGNsd7nT/wbY73Pm/g3xmrfZW1baFsf0hSlUjyXbwG/nCg9xV9Dbi5EFcXW6hMjNTykjkOpNd1EMJogG%20ytLstNIq644E9ewdz7AoFU7UOXAQAA)